# Major Issue with Session and Login

Tags: php, session, authentication

Ok ive been having this major problem with my site. Whats going on is as I'm going from page to page its is not maintaining its SESSION. Here are a couple source codes on the same directory. Ok so I have an index with a modal box that contains the iframe for login.php and logout.php. It logs me in but once I go to a different page It doesn't carry the session and then when I click login its says Im already logged in and has the session. Also how can I add cookies to my website I find those confusing.

Just snippets:

part of header.php goes on every page

```
<?php session_start(); if($_SESSION["username"]) { ?>

<div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 20px;">Hello <?php  echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php session_start(); require_once('connections/Main.php');

        if($_SESSION['username']) {

            echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You, '.$_SESSION['username'].' are already logged in.</div>';
            echo "<br />";
            echo "Go <a target='top' href='index.php'>back</a> to the page you were viewing before this.</li>";

            exit();
        }
    ... database funcctions go here then add session
    if($rowCheck > 0) { 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

          // Start the session and register a variable 

          session_start(); 
          $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
          //session_register('username'); 

          echo '<script> parent.document.location.href = "index.php"; </script>';

          }
```

logout.php

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php if($_SESSION['username']) {
    session_unset(); 
    session_destroy(); 
    header("Location: index.php"); } 
    else { header("Location: index.php"); } ?>
```

Comment: well `$_SESSION['username'] = $user; ` is setting up correctly check that out

Comment: does it have to do with the fact that the login is inside an iframe

Comment: session_start() is only put once on each page header.php is not included with login and logout

Comment: no it doesn't if you are fetching $_session correctly on the same server.

Comment: use session_start only once in login.php also in your demo: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in login.php on line 72

Comment: Does it happens in what browsers? If only in IE, [this page will help you](http://www.how2guru.com/archives/php-session-problem-while-using-iframe/)

Comment: ive fixed that syntax error so if yall would be kind enough to recheck it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was really wrong for anybody who has this problem. You must make sure every URL the user goes to is http://website.com or http://www.website.com but not mixed. You cannot have different pages with both of these or sessions will disappear. This is because with www it is stored in www/website/ and not just website/

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not stored server-side. The point of cookies is to have info stored on the browser so that the info is sustained between pages.They are recorded in client's browser.To store a cookie in an incoming client's browser you need to use

```
setcookie(<name-of-cookie>, <value>, <the time the cookie expires>, <path>, <domain>, <flag to indicate whether cookie is transmitted over HTTPS>)
```

Basically the first three parameters are used. The rest need not be mentioned if not necessary.
All the best.

Comment: How does that relate to the problem at hand?

Comment: how would you check for a cookie is it $_COOKIE['']

Comment: He asked about cookies. So I figured I would answer. Besides I could not comment on his question as I have not much score, else I would have done that.

Comment: you can check by isset() and you can retrieve the value of the cookie by $_COOKIE['cookie_name']